# In C# what is the benefit of passing value by ref?

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand what is the benefit of passing method params by ref in c# instead of passing parameters by value.

I have a list of custom objects (around 50k) and I need to run some operation on its properties. I have written a calculation class which accepts that list of 50K elements and returns the value. I am wondering if I pass the parameter by the ref, is it going to save my system memory in runtime as I am passing the reference and not passing a copy of the 50k list? How does .NET maintains this actually?

```
main(){
    var itemList={}//list containing 50k items
    var result=Calculate(itemList);// it passes a copy of the array
    var resultByRef=Calculate(ref itemList); //**it passes address of result variable, is it going to take less memory in runtime??**
}
private int Calculate(List<CustomClass> itemList){
    //do some calculation
    return result;
}
private int CalculateByRef(ref List<CustomClass> itemList){
    //do some calculation
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Even without `ref`, no copy will be made because `List<>` is a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types).

Comment: You first need to understand the difference between a `value type` and a `reference type`; then go look at the difference between passing "by ref" with respect to those two broad types.  When you pass a value type "by ref", this allows you to change the value and that change will be seen outside the method call back in the original variable.  When you pass a reference type "by ref" what this really means is that you can assign a NEW object to that variable and the original variable outside will also point to the new object.  Passing reference types "by ref" is not as common.

Comment: Ref keyword is mostly used on primitive types(int,float,etx..), since all objects in c# passes by references

Comment: In case you are using Parallel.For etc, you will find that code inside the loop cannot pass by ref variables to functions called from within the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are coming from C++ background like me.

In C# every object is passed around but its reference all the time which means no matter how large the object is, you always pass its reference to methods.

The only difference the `ref` keyword makes is give you ability to change that reference itself. Let's understand with an example:

```
static void callByRef(ref byte[] buff)
{
    buff[0] = 10;
    buff = new byte[5];
}

static void callNormally(byte[] buff)
{
    buff[0] = 10;
    buff = new byte[5];
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] param = new byte[5];
    param[0] = 5;

    Console.WriteLine("Original param.Hash: " + param.GetHashCode());
    callNormally(param);
    Console.WriteLine("param[0]: " + param[0]);
    Console.WriteLine("param.Hash: " + param.GetHashCode());
    callByRef(ref param);
    Console.WriteLine("param[0]: " + param[0]);
    Console.WriteLine("param.Hash: " + param.GetHashCode());
    return;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Origenal param.Hash: 58225482
param[0]: 10
param.Hash: 58225482
param[0]: 0
param.Hash: 54267293
```

In a normal call too, you can change the contents inside the object but in case of `ref` call the object itself can be changed.

In your case you are only worried about memory replication in case of passing large data as parameter to a method which happens in case of C++. In C# that is not the case.

Comment: Just to be clear, `List<T>` is not a linked list; it's a wrapper around an array of items of type T.

Comment: This answer is very clear to me. I saw many discussions on this but none can distinguish it in a better way. So what u are trying to say is, if the main method has an array of size 10 and it calls another method, that method won't be able to change that size. If we pass a ref of that array, then the external method can change the size too. That's the main benefit of using ref. Are my understandings sound good to you?

Comment: It has not only changed the size but object itself. Instead of size you can check for `param.GetHashCode()` and in case of passing with `ref` even that will change. I have  edited the answer for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

**Passing by reference will not help you here.**

This is because passing by value for a reference type list a list or array *still passes the reference*. The difference is when you pass by value, you pass a *copy* (value) of the reference, but it's *only the reference* that is copied. When you pass by reference you pass the original variable.

Copying a mere 20 byte reference isn't meaningfully different than what you need to do to make actual reference passing work, and so there's no performance advantage. Passing by reference is only useful if you need to change the variable itself: for example, assign a completely new List object to it.

```
//pass itemList by value
private int Calculate(List<CustomClass> itemList)
{
    itemList[0] = new CustomClass(); // this still works!
    //The List reference that was passed to this method still refers
    // to the *same List object* in memory, and therefore if we update
    // the item at position [0] here it will still be changed after the 
    // method returns.


    // But this does NOT change the original after the method ends,
    // because itemList is a different variable and we just changed
    // it to refer to a whole new object.
    itemList = new List<CustomClass>(); 
    // If we had instead passed this by reference, then the calling code
    // would also see the brand new list.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's work through the following example.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myLocalList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };    // 1
    myLocalList.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x)); // 2

    Calculate1(myLocalList);                        // 3
    myLocalList.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x)); // 5

    Calculate2(ref myLocalList);                    // 6
    myLocalList.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x)); // 8
}

private void Calculate1(List<int> list)
{
    list = new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 };               // 4
}

private void Calculate2(ref List<int> list)
{
    list = new List<int> { 7, 8, 9 };               // 7
}
```

- Step 1 creates a local list of integers initialized with values 1, 2, and 3.
- Step 2 prints the list.  The console output shows 1, 2, and 3 on separate lines.
- Step 3 calls `Calculate1` with the local list as a parameter input.
- Step 4 assigns the `list` variable a new list of integers with values 4, 5, and 6.
- Step 5 prints the list.  The console output shows 1, 2, and 3 on separate lines, same as Step 2.
- Step 6 calls `Calculate2` with the local list as a **ref** parameter input.
- Step 7 assigns the `list` variable a new list of integers with values 7, 8, and 9.
- Step 8 prints the list.  This time, the console output shows 7, 8, and 9 on separate lines.

When `myLocalList` is passed to `Calculate1`, the list is not copied.  To be absolutely clear, what I mean specifically is that the *contents* of `myLocalList` are **NOT** copied to the `list` parameter.  What is *copied*, however, is the reference to `myLocalList`.  In other words, the reference to `myLocalList` is copied *by value* to the `list` parameter.  When step 4 sets `list` to the new 4-5-6 list, the copied reference (i.e., `list`) is modified, not the original reference (i.e. `myLocalList`).

That changes with `Calculate2`.  In this case, the reference to `myLocalList` is passed *by reference* to the `list` parameter.  This effectively turns `list` into an alias for `myLocalList`, meaning that when step 7 sets `list` to the new 7-8-9 list, the original reference (i.e., `myLocalList`) is modified.  That's why the output changes in step 8.

> ...is it going to save my system memory in runtime as I am passing the
> reference and not passing a copy of the 50k list?

No.  Neither the `Calculate` nor the `CalculateByRef` methods receive deep copies of `itemList`, so performance is not impacted in the way you suggest.  Passing the parameter using the `ref` keyword in `CalculateByRef` simply allows you to modify the value of the `itemList` variable in `Main` from inside `CalculateByRef`.

Just based on what you've shown, it doesn't sound like you need the `ref` keyword in this case.

HTH